# Error al copiar una base de datos SQLite en android

Tags: android-sqlite

¿Podría orientarme alguien? Llevo un par de días liado con esto y falla.

Tengo un archivo .db de SQLite que contiene una base de datos vacía. la idea es copiarla a mi aplicación android desde el directorio assets, que está situado en src/main/assets.

Pero algo está fallando y no se qué es. sospecho donde está el fallo, pero no logro dar con la tecla. me crea una base de datos, pero la crea vacía (sin tablas).

Por si ayuda, el archivo DB es este:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbufam9ujo7y8cu/organizapp.db?dl=0

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
private String DB_PATH;
    private static String DB_NAME = "organizapp.db";
    ...

     * Crea una base de datos vacía en el sistema y la reescribe con nuestro
     * fichero de base de datos.
     * */
    private void createDataBase(){

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        this.getWritableDatabase();

        if(!dbExist) {

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error(myContext.getString(R.string.error_copiando_bd));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Comprueba si la base de datos existe para evitar copiar siempre el
     * fichero cada vez que se abra la aplicación.
     * @return true si existe, false si no existe
     */
    public boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        Log.d("Comprobando bd","Objeto a null");
        try{
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase
                    .openDatabase(this.DB_PATH,
                            null,
                            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            Log.d("Creando bd","No hay bd.");
            //si llegamos aqui es porque la base de datos no existe todavía.

        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();

        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copia nuestra base de datos desde la carpeta assets a la recién creada
     * base de datos en la carpeta de sistema, desde dónde podremos acceder a
     * ella.
     * Esto se hace con bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
Log.d("Copiando db","entramos.");
        //Abrimos el fichero de base de datos como entrada
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        Log.d("Creando bd","Abrimos"+DB_NAME);

        //Ruta a la base de datos vacía recién creada
        String outFileName = getDB_PATH();
        Log.d("Creando bd","apuntamos a "+getDB_PATH());

        //Abrimos la base de datos vacía como salida
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //Transferimos los bytes desde el fichero de entrada al de salida
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Liberamos los streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
        Log.d("Creando bd","BD Copiada");
    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: a que te refieres con que la crea vacia? la base que tienes en el dropbox no tiene datos solo tiene 3 tablas

Comment: Perdona, no fui suficientemente claro. Crea una base de datos sin tablas.